# Jasmine, Custom userAgent returns CORS origin error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular7

I've a test that gets the userAgent to detect if the device is a computer or a mobile device, but when I run the test I get CORS error.

This is the test code:

```
  it('should detect if device is mobile', () => {
    // Custom user agent
    window.navigator['__defineGetter__']('userAgent', function() {
     return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; PH-1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.99 Mobile Safari/537.36';
    });
    // component.getDevice();
    // fixture.detectChanges();
    const mobile = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div.dl-sidebar-backdrop.mobile'));
    expect(mobile).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

And this is the error:
[image]

I made a research but I didn't find any information related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a XHR call to somewhere not `localhost` that using `HttpClient` in your `SidebarComponent` I guess. Remove that logic and try again.

Comment: I don't have any HttpClient, even if I remove the custom userAgent the error disappear